# What happens if one of the multiple instances of the same service registered on Eureka server goes down?

Tags: microservices, load-balancing, spring-cloud, netflix-eureka, failover

I've started building a microservice application with the netflix stack, and have been successful in registering clients with the eureka discovery server.
I want to have two instances of each client service, 
and i'm wondering what happens if one instance of a client goes down. Does loadbalancing handle such situations ? If yes, then isn't eureka also acting as a failover system ?

Comment: Eureka on its own doesn't. It's usually used with a client side load balancer like ribbon and retry for certain errors

Comment: Thanks Spencer. Yes, you're right. It is ribbon which does the load balancing. Can you pls help me with docs/links where i can get more info on what kind of errors does ribbon retry /